# Screen turns off during call with Tecno F7

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, calls, screen

Why does my screen go off during a call? It doesn't turn on even when I press the power button. It only comes back after the call.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I have a Samsung Galaxy S4*

Just giving this a shot in case it works. Are you using the stock Phone app? Maybe you have the `Turn off screen during calls` checked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem, on reading this thread i checked on the proximity sensor on the Techno f7 and discovered it was somewhat blocked, i cleaned the blockade and everything went fine. The Proximity sensor is located at the right of the speaker it is a small oblong shaped spot.